# Sort using predefined function

Tags: java, sorting

I've got a sorting problem. I have a function, let's say blackbox to simplify.
As input it takes two jobs (tasks) and as output it returns the one to be processed first. For example:

```
input(1,2) --> output: Job 2 is first.
```

Problem is, this blackbox sometimes takes bad decisions.
Example: Suppose we have 3 jobs : 0, 1 and 2. We test each job against the other to identify a processing order.

```
input(0,1) --> output: Job 0 is first
input(1,2) --> output: Job 1 is first
input(0,2) --> output: Job 2 is first (bad decision)
```

So here's the problem, normally using the two fist input, job 0 have to be processed before 2. But the balckbox says otherwise.
I want using this blackbox sort a set of jobs, taking into consideration this problem.
So, how can I sort the set of jobs ?

Comment: The [`Comparator<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface exists to write your own sorting implementations that aren't part of the class being sorted.  It's mainly meant for use with [`Collections.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-).

Comment: If the black box does not work properly, then why use the black box? Implement your own logic (in a `Comparator`) that does the right thing, instead of the black box that doesn't work properly.

Comment: define bad decision, is it something the code can identify?

Comment: Why you think that choose 3 is bad decision?

Comment: Well actually this blackbox is a Decision Tree and it is doing some prediction, that is why it does not always return a good decision

Comment: @talex From the first line (example) job 0 is processed before 1. And 1 before 2. So logically 0 must go before 2. Which not the case in the example that is why it's a bad decision

Comment: Now I get it. Your initial version had mistyping. Why you think that last decision was wrong? Any of them could be wrong.

Comment: Yes, error on the initial, sorry. As you say maybe the first two decisions are wrong and the third is correct. I can't know for sure. But I have to find an order (sequence) for the jobs.

Answer (score 2):

There is easy to identify that problem exists. You need to build direct graph of decision. If it contains cycles than you have a bad decision somewhere.

But It is impossible to find out which decision is bad. Any decision in cycle can be bad (or even several of them).

*EDIT*

You can remove some edges of graph to break loop (you can chose it any way you like). After that you task will be partially ordered (or maybe totally ordered I need to think about it).

*EDIT 2*

Here is wiki article which may help you [Feedback arc set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feedback_arc_set)

Comment: I do understand your point. But a bad decision may be encountered, the question is how to sort taking this decision into consideration. Or do I correct this decision and then go back to the sorting?

Comment: @Zahzah The problem is that without a well-defined ordering, sorting is meaningless because the end state is arbitrary.